# How can I remove matlab on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, matlab, software-uninstall

I can't uninstall matlab from my Ubuntu 14.04. When I run `sudo apt-get purge matlab` then it shows the matlab configuration page but when I cancel the installation process then it shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'matlab' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 148 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.19) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I uninstall matlab?

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to delete the folder that has your matlab installation. That's it.

---

However **if** you have a license manager you first need to shut it down and remove its files. I didn't need to do this but here you go:

- To shut it down: there should be a file called `lmdown` in your matlab folder in the `etc` folder. Run it.
- To remove its files: run `sudo rm /var/tmp/lm_TMW*`

Also you might want to remove symlinks to matlab binaries. Run:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/mcc /usr/local/bin/mex /usr/local/bin/mbuild
```

...Also don't forget to remove `matlab-support`. Run:

```
sudo apt-get purge matlab-support
```

[Source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102428-how-do-i-uninstall-matlab-products-on-a-unix-or-linux-machine)

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get purge matlab-support` in a Terminal to remove it.

Comment: nooooo no `matlab-support` is just a metapackage and has nothing to do with matlab ..normally matlab is installed by its script so `purge matlab` won't work in the first place. notice `Package 'matlab' is not installed, so not removed` above